# SQL Server DateTime2(0) vs Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

What are the implications of using SQL Server's DateTime2 with a precision of 0 to represent a date rather than the built in Date field.

In either case, my concern is to prevent accidental time entries, but are there storage or performance considerations I should take note of?

Comment: `DateTime2(0)` still allows you to store time. `Date` will not.

Comment: Do you mean DateTime2 v/s DateTime? DateTime2 adds more [precision](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to the time part of the value..

Comment: @abhi, nope. I saw a difference in a project I was maintaining and wonder why the difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It won't work. According to MSDN the minimum size of Datetime2 is six bytes and will contain hh:mm:ss so it can, and will, contain a time component (default of midnight). As other responders have noted you must use a date type to guarantee that not time portion is saved and will occupy three bytes.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 25):

`DateTime2(0)` will store datetime with no decimal values i.e `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DateTime2(0) , GETDATE())
RESULT: 2015-04-06 20:47:17
```

Storing data just as dates will only store dates i.e `YYYY-MM-DD` without any time values.

```
SELECT CONVERT(Date , GETDATE())
RESULT:  2015-04-06
```

If you are only interested in dates then use `DATE` data type.

`DATETIME2` will use `6 bytes` for precisions `less than 3` and `DATE` will use `3 bytes`.

Date is half the size of DATETIME(0) hence it will also perform better since sql server will process less data and will save disk space as well.

Comment: How-to show DATE with format dd/MM/yyyy ? CONVERT(Date , FechaIni) or CAST(FechaIni AS DATE)

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder which I ran into myself when I converted a couple of DATETIME2(0) columns to DATE to make sure it aligned better with the value in the column (date only).

When using DATE you cannot use things like `SELECT MyDate + 1 FROM..`  or  `WHERE MyDate>0`  while when using DATETIME2 you can, at least not in MS-SQL. Ofcourse IMHO it doesn't make any sense why DATETIME2 will allow you to do it and DATE not.